# EF 5 - how to implement OnContextCreated & onObjectMaterialized?

Tags: entity-framework-5

In my ongoing attempt to use EF 5 as it was designed, I am using the DbContext over ObjectContex and started with fresh templates.

As I understand it, I should now be overriding SaveChanges instead of creating an event handler and assigning it to SavingChanges.  No problem, works great.

But how to I do the equivalent of defining an onObjectMaterialized event and assigning it to ObjectMaterialized (which I need as I have to massage some data as it's loaded.)

Same questions with OnContextCreated...

In EF 4, I edited the templates and the generated code which had support for these.  I can't seem to figure out the equivalent implementation in EF 5.

Thanks!